# How to salvage a git commit with a keyboard interrupt

Tags: git, git-commit

I had a handful of files I wanted to commit, but was planning on committing them in smaller groups so as to have a clean history in case I wanted to review/rollback.  I went to commit a subset, but realized I missed one.  While git commit was running, I did a Ctrl + C keyboard interrupt (instinct for killing a process, obviously not the right move here).  I found that git wiped my local files & was totally lost in the history, so much that i had to delete the local branch & pull it again.  I couldn't find my files anywhere, not even with git fsck & looking though all the dangling blobs/commits.

I think the answer to this question is, "yeah, don't ever do that" but was curious if anyone else had ever made the same mistake but happened to know a way to recover & not end up losing a bunch of work.

Late nights can definitely make a mess. :-)

Answer (score 0):

That could only happen if you do a [`git commit -a -m "a commit message"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298990/6309)  (or some kind of alias).

The best way to avoid this is always to add, then commit.

And the best way (for me) to add is to use the --patch option:

```
git add -p
```

That way, I not only add file by file, but also chunk by chunk within each modified file, in order to make coherent commits.