# Git complains about "trailing whitespace" and "tab before indent" after it has been removed

Tags: git, spaces

I am working on a large project with a git repository. It is picky, so every time I push something it complains about white spaces and tabs. But this time, after I have manually made sure that the file I am uploading does not have tabs, the message after git commit does not change

```
git commit

sth/sth-else.hh:81: space before tab in indent.
```

do I need to refresh git somehow to notice that the file was changed?

Comment: If you change a file you have to stage the changes with `git add` so it will be committed with the next `git commit` command.

Comment: How did you fix this?  Is there a `git` command or `unix` command that will fix these issues?

Answer (score 2):

You need to restage those files, via `git add` or `git commit -a` (though I would not recommend the latter for other reasons).

edit : found it \o/ the first paragraph of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4298990/1573542) explains why `git commit -a` isn't the best choice :)