# Run an external program upon git add a specific file with the specific file as a parameter

Tags: git, batch-file, github

So here's the thing, I've got a binary file that I can `git diff` using `iconv` via the `git bash` using this type of convertion method.

```
textconv = "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE"
```

I'm not sure if the binary file encoding is `ISO-8859-1` because there are a lot of special characters left whenever I use `git diff`.

**Main problem**: I cannot view the diff on our github. So what I did was to convert the binary file to a much readable file to get rid of all those special characters. My lil piece of code produces an `.xml` file. I want to include this file as a `source code` basis so that whenever a merge request is made, the need for a `git diff` via `bash` is eliminated.

**What I'm after**: I would like to execute the program upon using `git add` on a specific file. I've read about `aliases`, but I'm not exactly sure how to use the file as a parameter, and to invoke it whenever the specific file type is added. Should I modify the program to read the file type?

**Summary**: Upon using `git add` (or maybe an *alias*) on a **specific file type**, I would like to run an **external command** to convert the **file**, then invoke **git add** to include the **converted file**.

TIA :)

**UPDATE:** I am now experimenting with `alias` and assign it as i.e. `add-filetype = "!../convert.er my.file && git commit my.file -m 'Auto-generated file on filetype add'"` so I can just run `git add-filetype my.file`.

**Solution**:
Finally I came up with this on my gitconfig:

```
[alias]
    add-filetype = "!f(){ \
                        ../convert.er $1; \
                        git add $1.xml; \
                        git commit $1.xml -m \"Auto Generate XML file\"; \
                    ); f"
```

and simple type `git add-filetype my.file` on git-bash.

Thanks @VonC!

Comment: use a [bash function](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/472/functions#t=201608040231154732658) .. aliases cannot accept arguments..

Comment: Well, I can always use the exclamation mark (!) to run a command to indicate that the command is an external shell command via alias right? Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299159/1809168

Comment: I don't know about that, but if it solves your problem, why not?

Comment: Thank you, but could you please expand on your answer? I am now experimenting with alias and assign it as i.e. add-filetype = "!../convert.er my.file && git commit my.file -m 'Auto-generated file on filetype add'" so I can just run git add-filetype my.file

Comment: I wasn't clear in earlier comment.. am not familiar with workings of git.. if what you tried worked, you can add it as answer with explanation and link to that SO answer.. my initial understanding was you needed a bash function which accepts any filename..

Comment: Well I could do that, but afaik bash is for linux based machines right? Our release team uses windows, so I'm now looking into working with batch files. I'd do what your suggesting, alias an external batch command that accepts the filename as a parameter and see what happens. Apologies, I believe that I may have tagged the question incorrectly.

Comment: yeah.. but you could use git-bash on windows if you like.. https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Comment: I didn't know that bash commands applies to git-bash as well. Thanks for the info.

Comment: This seems like the sort of problem better solved with a [build automation tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) such as `make`. This can fire a command anytime a file has changed, and requires no special git configuration for others work on your project.

Comment: Thank you for this info, I'm currently reading it and will get back to you once I'm done.

Comment: I will try your solution @Schwern. The task I am aiming to achieve has been accomplished atm. I will further tweak on `make` so that the process of executing my alias will no longer be needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> afaik bash is for linux based machines right? Our release team uses windows, so I'm now looking into working with batch files

That will work: git uses [git-bash bases on msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309), which means any Linux command in the git alias will be interpreted by that shell, even on Windows.

```
my_alias = "!f() { 〈your complex command〉 }; f"
```

See "[One weird trick for powerful Git aliases](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2014/10/advanced-git-aliases/) "

---

The [OP Eduard Daduya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1809168/eduard-daduya) embedded the script in the alias:

```
[alias]
    add-filetype = "!f(){ \
                        ../convert.er $1; \
                        git add $1.xml; \
                        git commit $1.xml -m \"Auto Generate XML file\"; \
                    ); f"
```

But that same script could have been written as:

`git-add-filetype`:

```
/full/path/to/convert.er $1
git add $1.xml; \
git commit $1.xml -m \"Auto Generate XML file\"
```

Any `git-xxx` script (no extension, in the `%PATH%`) can be called as `git xxx`: no git alias needed in that case.

Comment: Thank you for this info, I'll digest this after a few minutes and I'll get back to you once I'm done.

Comment: @EduardDaduya Note: I have edited the answer with an alternative to git alias.

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not seem to follow. I made the `add-filetype` alias so that whenever I type `git add-filetype` those lines of codes would be executed.

Comment: are you saying from `[alias]
    add-filetype = "!f(){ \
                        ../convert.er $1; \
                        git add $1.xml; \
                        git commit $1.xml -m \"Auto Generate XML file\"; \
                    ); f"` to `[alias]
    add-filetype = "../convert.er $1; \
                        git add $1.xml; \
                        git commit $1.xml -m \"Auto Generate XML file\";"` instead?

Comment: @EduardDaduya Exactly: my point is: without alias, you could have made a shell script (yes, even on Windows since it will be interpreted by the Git bash), called `git-add-filetype` (no extension), to be put anywhere in your `%PATH%`, because any script called `git-xxx` can be called with `git xxx`.

Comment: @EduardDaduya so no, I am not saying "from alias to alias". I am saying; this is an alternative to git alias, especially when you have complex scripts.

Comment: I understand now, instead of putting it in my gitconfig, I can simply put the command in `%PATH%` :)

Comment: @EduardDaduya Yes, that is the idea.