# Add and commit a specific file in one line

Tags: git

I have two files **not staged** for commmit:

- src/A.java
- src/B.java

I want add and commit B.java in one line. What is the most convenient way to this, like a one liner.

**I'm aware of `git commit -am "Commit message"`**, I need to do it for **specific file**

Comment: git add B.java && git commit -m 'comment'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git add and commit in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298960/git-add-and-commit-in-one-command)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, git commit -am "Commit message". Adds everything, i just need a specific file

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)? The answer is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also run either:

```
git commit --only <paths>
```

(add `-m <message>` if desired), or:

```
git commit --include <paths>
```

(again, add `-m <message>` if desired).  This—to oversimplify it a bit—has the effect of adding the specified paths to the index (`--include`) or to a temporary index (`--only`), then committing using the index you chose with `--only` vs `--include`.

If you used `--include`, the completed commit that becomes the new HEAD commit on the current branch is automatically represented by the augmented index.  This case is the simpler one to describe: it really does work as if you had `git add`ed those files, since it carries along any earlier `git add`ed files.

If you used `--only`, the completed commit that becomes the new HEAD represents something that's not necessarily in the *normal* index.  This case is more complicated, since the index should normally represent (and hence contain all the same files as) the HEAD commit until you start `git add`ing files to overwrite the index versions.  The internal details here are that Git copies the `--only` files to the regular index after the new commit is safely installed.

Retaining the oversimplification (because all versions really use some special temporary index files), we can diagram this as:

- Normal commit: uses *the* index as the source for all the files committed.  After the commit completes, the index is still the index, and still contains all the files.

  Hence, if you `git add fileA` and then `git commit`, the new commit has the new `fileA` (and the same old every-other-file as before).  The index and the new `HEAD` commit match.
- `git commit --include <file>`: Acts a lot like `git add` followed by `git commit`.

  Hence, if you `git add fileA` and then `git commit --include fileB`, the new commit has the new `fileA` and the new `fileB` (and the same old every-other-file as before).  The index and the new `HEAD` commit match.
- `git commit --only <file>`: Copies the `HEAD` commit to a temporary index, adds `<file>` to the temporary index, and runs `git commit` using the temporary index.  On success, adds `<file>` to *the* index as well.

  Hence, if you `git add fileA` and then `git commit --only fileB`, the new commit has the *old* `fileA` (from the previous `HEAD` commit), the *new* `fileB` (from the temporary index), and the same old every-other-file as before.  The index *after* committing has the new `fileA` and the new `fileB`, so the index after committing differs from the new `HEAD` commit in that it has a different version of `fileA`.

Answer (score 3):

Since [`git commit -am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit--a) would add everything, you still need to add first, then commit, but at least you can do it in one line

```
git add src/B.java && git commit -m "add B"
```

The point is, there is no native Git command for adding and committing just one file (or a subset of the modified files)