# why does git commit -am giving me an error?

Tags: git

I am trying to use:
git commit -am but I am getting an error command not recognized I used it before but now it's not recognized.
the command is git add & git commit combined.

Answer (score 0):

if `git add .` and `git commit -m <commit message>` are working. Then `git commit -am <commit message>` should work.

Please check with first two commands, then try yours.
[image]

Comment: as you can see in the photo the add and commit are working but the am not working
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iohtEYPbUmYKpaMtOqF1TwBhe5EpWdBy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The image needs to be made public

Comment: I changed it you can check now

Comment: git add & commit command:
`git commit -am "Enter Your Message within Double Quotation Marks".`

You entered command like `git commit -am "trying am" file1`. What is this? Please remove `file1` text from your command. I don't know why you did tricky. 


For more details check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298960/git-add-and-commit-in-one-command    https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html

Comment: the file1 is like saying I want this commit only on this file

Comment: Run `git status` and check what file/s have changed (It shows in red color by default). Then run `git commit -am <copy file path from git status>`. It should work.. 
         check screenshot:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjBv6.png

Comment: `the file1 is like saying I want this commit only on this file`.. You need to use `git add <filename>` and then `git commit -m "Message"`

Comment: Yes, there are two ways to push a particular file. First, run `git status` and check which file you did. \n   Way-01: `git add <specific file path>`↵   `git commit -m "<enter message>"`↵  `git push origin <branch name>`↵ .   Way-02: `git commit -am <specific file path>`↵  `git push origin <branch name>`↵.