# Git - Why this command does not add the file in my repository?

Tags: git

I am using git and most of the time we use this command to add files in our repository. `git add .` and after that we write a commit message like this `git commit -m "add file info.js"` . But I came across with this command `git commit -am "message"`. If I have not created a new file this will stage the commit and send the commit with a message.

But If I create a new file like `file.js` the command does push the latest code on my repository but not the new file. I wonder why. Can somebody please explain me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git commit -m vs. git commit -am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877818/git-commit-m-vs-git-commit-am)

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. If you search the web for "git commit "am"", you'll find the linked duplicate as well as the documentation, explaining: _"git commit -a automatically stage **all tracked, modified files** before the commit"_. So it doesn't add new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because some of your files are not staged. This happens when you delete/add files that are not currently being tracked.

[-a documentation:](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--a)

> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified
>   and deleted, **but new files you have not told Git about are not
>   affected.**

Eventually you would need to do still a `git add .` when you add/delete files that are not currently being tracked.